# Helm conditionally install subchart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is there a way to conditionally install a helm subchart based on global values.yaml? I've all my internal services and components as subcharts, and one of them is a messagequeue chart. In my dev and test environment (local k8s), I use RabbitMQ, and in staging and Prod (AKS), I use Azure Service Bus. Based on the namespace/values.yaml, I want to install rabbitmq or not.

P.S - I've created all the components as subcharts so that they are all part of a single release.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

***Update:***
With helm 3.0 release and Chart version v2, the chart dependencies have to be added in Chart.yaml instead of a separate requirements.yaml file. So if you are using apiVersion=v2 in helm 3, see the [helm v2->v3 changes](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/v2_v3_migration/). This would then be:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: myapplication
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: 1.0

dependencies:
  - name: apidocs
    condition: apidocs.enabled
```

---

I've found out the answer:

In requirements.yaml, add:

```
dependencies:
- name: api
  condition: api.enabled
- name: messagequeue
  condition: messagequeue.enabled
```

and in values.yaml, add

```
api:
  enabled: true    
messagequeue:
  enabled: false
```

Now during installation, pass the values to enabled or disable the messagequeue as follows:

```
helm install --dry-run --debug website\ --set messagequeue.enabled=true
```

or

```
helm install --dry-run --debug website\ --set messagequeue.enabled=false
```

Comment: So it works for rendering templates when managing subcharts via `requirements.yaml`. However, such dependency w/o repository would fail commands including `helm dep up` and `helm dep build`. b/c of issue https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3742

Answer (score 3):

### Using Helm version v3.4.1.

I was having this error.

[helm chart with requirements.yaml, did not find local charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770636/helm-chart-with-requirements-yaml-did-not-find-local-charts/65771872#65771872)

["helm dep build" fails if requirements.yaml contains local dependencies and remote one #3742](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3742).

My solution was to:

- Rename `charts/` (directory) to `subcharts/`
- And `chmod 755 subcharts/*`

Heml 3 didn't like it when I placed my local dependencies in `charts/`
Also Helm dep up needs permissions to move the local dependencies from your subcharts directory to `tmpcharts/` and so on.

**

### This is not my find.

**

I read this from  @sgandon :

Bug documented [#3742](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3742).
[comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3742#issuecomment-384582792).

> the reason why the os.Stat() fails to find the folder.    This is
> because the calling function
> [downloadAll](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/b6335b7dfeb0e68952ee914877fe456ecd257779/pkg/downloader/manager.go#L212)      is renaming the charts folder to tmpcharts during the update
> thus making our unpacked chart not foundable for that duration.

Note:

!! On Helm 3 requirements.yaml is deprecated. !!

You add the dependencies in the Parent/Main Charts.yaml.

```
dependencies:
  - name: chart-you-want-to-deploy-1
    repository: file://subcharts/chart-you-want-to-deploy-1
    version: 0.0.1
    condition: chart-you-want-to-deploy-1.enabled

  - name: chart-you-want-to-deploy-2
    repository: file://subcharts/chart-you-want-to-deploy-2
    version: 0.0.1
    condition: chart-you-want-to-deploy-2e.enabled
```

Added my variables to my globals in the Parent/Main Values.yaml

```
globals:
  chart-you-want-to-deploy-1:
    enabled: true
  chart-you-want-to-deploy-2:
    enabled: false
```

Dont forget to add the flags to your command.
In my case I was using a CI/CD tool (Gitlab)

```
script:
    - >
      helm dep up Main-Chart-Name && \
       helm upgrade --install \
       --set chart-you-want-to-deploy-1.enabled=false \
       --set chart-you-want-to-deploy-2.enabled=true \
       RELEASE_NAME Main-Chart-Name
```

my tree

```
Main-Chart-Name
├── Chart.yaml
├── subcharts
│   ├── chart-you-want-to-deploy-1
│   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   ├── charts
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── chart-you-want-to-deploy-1.yaml
│   │   └── values.yaml
│   └── chart-you-want-to-deploy-2
│       ├── Chart.yaml
│       ├── charts
│       ├── templates
│       │   └── chart-you-want-to-deploy-2.yaml
│       └── values.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── helpers.tpl
│   ├── my.yaml
│   ├── main.yaml
│   └── templates.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

P.S. - Thank you @Narayana and @sgandon . Thanks to you guys I'm happy deploying!

Comment: I tried this and get `Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: chart-you-want-to-deploy-1`. Do you have any idea about this error?

Comment: Yes, I got that when I placed my subcharts in the directory called `charts/`

That is why I created the `subcharts/` directory.
Make sure helm have permissions to play with those directries. 
I did chmod 755 charts/ subcharts/ templates/

The reason it throws that error is because Helm Dep will try to zip and move around the files.
Try this and let me know how you get on

Comment: I tried this. It worked for the most part, however there's one issue i ran into. My subchart has a remote dependency itself. when i do `helm dep up`, the subchart does not get it's pull its remote dependencies pulled. so i have to first go into that subchart'ss directory, do a `helm dep up` then return to the project root and do a `helm dep up` again before it works properly. it seems helm dep up is not recursive.

Comment: When I had this issue I just needed to ensure that the name of the dependency matched up to the chart folder. My guess is due to helm automatically created dependencies for anything in `charts/` so you have to match that name to get it to find the dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I tried that now in 2022 and did the following:

in chart.yaml:

```yaml
dependencies:
  - name: db
    version: 0.1.0
    condition: db.enabled

  - name: mailer
    version: 0.1.0
    condition: mailer.enabled
```

Then i added in values.yaml of the main chart:

```yaml
db:
  enabled: true
  ...
mailer:
  enabled: true
  ....
```

and added my subcharts db and mailer to the charts directory.
Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this (ugly) workaround as answer borrowed from [@sgandon](https://github.com/sgandon): https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3742#issuecomment-383095917

`dependencies:
  - name: mobi-postgresql
    version: 1.0.1
    repository: "@mobi"
    alias: postgresql
  - name: oraclepdb
    version: 0.0.1
    repository: "file://subcharts/oraclepdb"
    condition: oraclepdb.enabled`

Then you can use the practice [*Chart dependencies*](https://helm.sh/docs/charts/#chart-dependencies) to manage subcharts as dependencies via `helm dep update` and `helm dep build`.

It's not beautiful as long as [this bug](https://github.com/sgandon) is not fixed.