# helm chart with requirements.yaml, did not find local charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm

my charts has elasticsearch and mongdb dependencies, and in my charts, the structure like this:

```
├── [-rw-rw-r--]  Chart.yaml
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  dependency_charts
│   ├── [drwxrwxr-x]  elasticsearch
│   └── [drwxrwxr-x]  mongodb
├── [-rw-rw-r--]  deploy.sh
├── [-rw-rw-r--]  requirements.yaml
├── [-rw-rw-r--]  values.yaml
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  templates
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  proj-deploy.yaml
│   └── [-rw-rw-r--]  proj-svc.yaml
```

but when I try to install my chart, it will say:

`Error: found in requirements.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: elasticsearch, mongodb`

and when I execute helm dep ls, it show status missing

```
$ helm dep list
NAME            VERSION REPOSITORY                              STATUS
elasticsearch   6.5.1   file://dependency_charts/elasticsearch  missing
mongodb         4.0.3   file://dependency_charts/mongodb        missing
```

the version is appVersion, and I have also change the version to chart version, it doesn't work.

this is the official document: https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_dependency.md 
https://docs.helm.sh/chart_best_practices/#repository-urls

this is helm version

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.10.0", GitCommit:"9ad53aac42165a5fadc6c87be0dea6b115f93090", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.10.0", GitCommit:"9ad53aac42165a5fadc6c87be0dea6b115f93090", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

And I can put those chart to a `charts` folder, but if I do that, helm will install mongodb and elasticsearch in the same charts, that's not expected, what I'm expecting is under the same namespace has three charts: myproj, elasticsearch, mongodb.

Anyone got a clue about what I do wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: use the requirements.yaml and for elasticsearch and mongodb they already exists as charts

Comment: @c4f4t0r, thanks your answer, current I don't want to pull charts from outside environment, I want to use local charts. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: sorry for external link https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/

Comment: @c4f4t0r, thanks, I have look though that page, and official document also can be find at here https://docs.helm.sh/chart_best_practices/#repository-urls , so I'm try to find what's wrong in my operation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Using Helm version v3.4.1.

I was having this error.

My solution was to:

- Rename `charts/` (directory) to `subcharts/`
- And `chmod 755 subcharts/*`

Heml 3 didn't like it when I placed my local dependencies in `charts/`
Also Helm dep up needs permissions to move the local dependencies from your subcharts directory to `tmpcharts/` and so on.

**

### This is not my find.

**

I read this from  @sgandon and @Narayana:

[Post about conditionally deploying helm charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032974/helm-conditionally-install-subchart)

Bug documented [#3742](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3742).
[comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3742#issuecomment-384582792).

> the reason why the os.Stat() fails to find the folder.    This is
> because the calling function
> [downloadAll](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/b6335b7dfeb0e68952ee914877fe456ecd257779/pkg/downloader/manager.go#L212)      is renaming the charts folder to tmpcharts during the update
> thus making our unpacked chart not foundable for that duration.

Note:

!! In Helm 3 requirements.yaml is deprecated. !!

You add the dependencies in the Parent/Main Charts.yaml.

```
dependencies:
  - name: chart-you-want-to-deploy-1
    repository: file://subcharts/chart-you-want-to-deploy-1
    version: 0.0.1
    condition: chart-you-want-to-deploy-1.enabled

  - name: chart-you-want-to-deploy-2
    repository: file://subcharts/chart-you-want-to-deploy-2
    version: 0.0.1
    condition: chart-you-want-to-deploy-2.enabled
```

Added my variables to my globals in the Parent/Main Values.yaml

```
globals:
  chart-you-want-to-deploy-1:
    enabled: true
  chart-you-want-to-deploy-2:
    enabled: false
```

Don't forget to add the flags to your command.
In my case I was using a CI/CD tool (GitLab).

```
script:
    - >
      helm dep up Main-Chart-Name && \
       helm upgrade --install \
       --set chart-you-want-to-deploy-1.enabled=false \
       --set chart-you-want-to-deploy-2.enabled=true \
       RELEASE_NAME Main-Chart-Name
```

my tree

```
Main-Chart-Name
├── Chart.yaml
├── subcharts
│   ├── chart-you-want-to-deploy-1
│   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   ├── charts
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── chart-you-want-to-deploy-1.yaml
│   │   └── values.yaml
│   └── chart-you-want-to-deploy-2
│       ├── Chart.yaml
│       ├── charts
│       ├── templates
│       │   └── chart-you-want-to-deploy-2.yaml
│       └── values.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── helpers.tpl
│   ├── my.yaml
│   ├── main.yaml
│   └── templates.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

Comment: It happened to me coz I had run one of the help command with sudo. I had to delete the tmpcharts to fix the issue. No need to rename etc..

Answer (score 15):

You have to run `helm dep update`. This will put subcharts into the ./charts  folder and create ./requirements.lock file. Then you can install.

Answer (score 7):

```
helm dep update
```

only works when the repo list is empty. Check `helm repo list` ,  if this return something then local dependencies will not resolve. Try removing the repos using command `helm repo remove REPO_NAME`

Answer (score 2):

> ... what I'm expecting is under the same namespace has three charts: myproj, elasticsearch, mongodb.

You need to run `helm install` three separate times to get that effect.

---

The `requirements.yaml` mechanism causes Helm to install multiple sub-charts in a single Helm release.  `helm list` would just show `myproj`, but internally it would also have the Kubernetes resources for the other components.  If you `kubectl get service` then you'd see Service objects like `unusual-animal-myproj` and `unusual-animal-mongodb`, managed by the same Helm release.  If you `helm del unusual-animal`, it would delete all three components together.

If that's the behavior you want, then the error message you got means what it says: the local charts must be in a subdirectory named exactly `charts`.  Running `helm dep up` or `helm dep build` will copy them there.

Comment: Thanks you explanation, I got it that, helm install can't install multiple charts in the same namespace. And as you said, after I install myproj, the service name and pod name has `unusual-animal-` prefix.

And you mentioned local charts must be in a subdirectory named exactly `charts`, but why the document take `repository: "file://../dependency_chart/nginx"` as an example, is it an typo error ? And after I modify requirements.yaml to `repository: "file://./charts/elasticsearch"`, helm dep ls show `unpacked` status, is it right?

Answer (score 1):

```
helm dep update <name_of_folder_where_chart.yaml_is>
```

Once you run above below will be the output:-

```
Saving 1 charts
Deleting outdated charts
```

Now, you can run your charts locally using

```
helm template <path_to_chart.yaml>
```