# Build Helm chart with custom app version for Sub Charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm

For a regular helm-chart I can use `helm package --app-version="foo-bar"` to be able to overwrite app-version while packing the helm chart.

Is there a way to achieve the same with sub-charts.

Consider the following helm-chart structure

```
uber-chart
    \sub-chart-1
    \sub-chart-2
    \sub-chart-3
```

Is it possible to pass different app-versions to different sub-charts while packaging `uber-chart`?

Comment: The way I do it is to have a Chart.yaml.sed file. And, with the install script, I use sed to replace the version in Chart.yaml.sed file and then finally copy to Chart.yaml. And, then git restore the changes to Chart.yaml.sed file and run helm install on the parent chart.

Comment: Yes, we can try such work arounds. I wanted to see if there is any option to do it out of the box using helm options.

Comment: Probably this is of use:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770636/helm-chart-with-requirements-yaml-did-not-find-local-charts

https://faun.pub/helm-conditions-and-tagging-for-umbrella-charts-f0ca9f6bb499