# Only install helm subchart resource if it does not exist

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart which I use to deploy an app that requires a number of credentials to run. I would like to be able to deploy the chart in different releases inside the namespace, editing certain settings between releases. The credential should be stored in secrets that are *release independent* so that there is only one instance of each secret in the namespace even if multiple releases are using them.

I would like to include a subchart that deploys the secrets as a dependency in the main chart and only install the resources if they have not been installed before.

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032974/helm-conditionally-install-subchart) which uses conditions for its dependencies, but they are set as values. Is there a way to make the subchart only deploy if there is not already a set of resources with the names present? Or would it be possible for the subchart to be its own release and only redeployed if there was a mismatch in version?

Comment: Great question, I would also like to know. My situation is that I want to ensure that `ingress-nginx` is installed, but I don't want it installed more than once.